# Upgrade Angular 2.x Application into Angular 8.x version - Need some thoughts on Angular update guide warning

Tags: angular

We want to update existing Angular 2.x app to Angular 8.x version, but while going through the [Angular Update Guide](https://update.angular.io/#2.0:8.0) it showing warning for major version updates and still guides the steps.

Please see the attached image.

And suggest the possibilities on application upgrade or does it require application rewrite ?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Are you asking what this warning means? If so, it means that they do not recommend upgrading from 2 to 8, but rather from 2 to 4, then 4 to 5, then 5 to 6, hen 6 to 7, then 7 to 8, i.e. one major version at a time.

Comment: Yes, I was asking for meaning as well as suggestion whether would be better to re-write application instead nested version upgrade. Thanks for your comments